# How to implement DataBinding in SAPUI5 when using XML-Views?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

in SAPUI5 assigning a model or data binding to a table or something is very easy, when using JS-Views.
But how can I do this, when using XML-Views?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<core:View
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
    xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    controllerName="view.Main">
    <Panel text="Hello World from an XML view">
        <Button text="Button" press="doSomething"></Button>
        <table:Table width="100%" visibleRowCount="5" selectionMode="Single" editable="false">
            <table:title><Label text="Wochentage"></Label></table:title>
            <table:Column>
                <Label text="ID" />
                <table:template><TextField value="{id}"></TextField></table:template>
            </table:Column>

        </table:Table>
    </Panel>
</core:View>
```

I dont want to give the table a fix id attribute and implement it by calling

```
sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("idProductsTable").setModel(

            demoJSONModel);
```

in the controller ... :(

Comment: Are you asking how to set the model on the table, or how to bind, say, the entries in the model to rows in the table?

Comment: I dont know how to do both. But binding is more important, because of the nature, that the related model will be searched in the DOM if I use a Model id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would normally set a model on a control (either the table directly, or one of its parents) in the controller. So I'm going to assume you're wondering about the latter part of your initial statement: "assigning a data binding to a table ... when using XML-Views".

All you have to do is express the aggregation as an XML attribute. So if your demoJSONModel looked like this:

```
var demoJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  data : [
    { id : 42 },
    { id : 1.618 },
    { id : 3.14 }
  ]
});
```

then you could set the binding for the table's 'rows' aggregation like this:

```
<table:Table
  width="100%"
  visibleRowCount="5"
  selectionMode="Single"
  editable="false"
  rows="{/data}">
```

I've put together [an example in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zoqop/5/edit) that shows this.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Your example seems to work, but i still cant get it to work on my own example... ;)

Comment: When I attach the model direct to the view I am able to assign the path via rows-attribute. Thats right and now I also got it to work in my own example, although the rows attribute is not valid as far as I can see by xsd.

But when I try to include a Model name like rows="{Menus>/data}", it doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/vocusimi/1/edit

Comment: You need to specify the model name in each binding, so this <TextField value="{id}"> needs to be this: <TextField value="{Numbers>id}">.

Comment: Here is a working JSBin example for the "named model" syntax: http://jsbin.com/gonafa/1/edit?html,js,output